# CodeDeploy on IIS server gives this error at download bundle stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis

Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/ongoing-deployment/

This error is resolved if I RDP inside the instance and try to restart the codedeploy agent. But I use a customised AMI with ASG group, so it won't help for new instance launched when scaled out. I can't go and RDP each time for the new instance.

I tried to add this command `powershell.exe -Command Restart-Service -Name codedeployagent` on user-data script to allow restart of agent on IIS (same command while I RDP to the instance as Administrator), but it does not have any effect
I have IAM role present on both codedeployment group and ec2 instance which is behind ALB and ASG.